# Index is outside the array bounds in a while loop

Tags: c#

I have a question concerning this piece of code that I'm writing. The purpose of this code should be like the game Reversi or Othello. So, you have a playing board and every time you click, you can make a new circle. If a player has a circle in between two circles of the other player, the circle changes color. This is how you make points. For example: red = r and blue = b, empty = 0. The board is as follows: r b 0. Now, it is reds turn and red does this r b r. This makes the blue circle change color to red. So the board now says r r r, scoring red an extra point, while blue loses one.
  It should check this for the whole line, but it doesn't do this. I get an error saying the index is outside the array bounds.
If you need more code, I would be happy to provide you.
  Thanks.

```
public void makeMoveArray(int x, int y, int a, int b, int color)
    {
        boardArray[x, y] = color;
        while (boardArray[x + a, y + b] != turn)
        {
            boardArray[x + a, y + b] = color;
            x += a;
            y += b;
        }
    }

    public void makeMove(int x, int y, int a)
    {
        if (lockedIn(x, y, 0, 1)) { this.makeMoveArray(x, y, 0, 1, a); }
        if (lockedIn(x, y, 1, 0)) { this.makeMoveArray(x, y, 1, 0, a); }
        if (lockedIn(x, y, 1, 1)) { this.makeMoveArray(x, y, 1, 1, a); }
        if (lockedIn(x, y, -1, 0)) { this.makeMoveArray(x, y, -1, 0, a); }
        if (lockedIn(x, y, 0, -1)) { this.makeMoveArray(x, y, 0, -1, a); }
        if (lockedIn(x, y, -1, -1)) { this.makeMoveArray(x, y, -1, -1, a); }
        if (lockedIn(x, y, 1, -1)) { this.makeMoveArray(x, y, 1, -1, a); }
        if (lockedIn(x, y, -1, 1)) { this.makeMoveArray(x, y, -1, 1, a); }

        panel1.Refresh();
    }
```

Comment: Use breakpoints, see what value is incorrect when indexing array. Exception is clear what went wrong. It should be easy for you to debug and find an error

Comment: When dealing with an array take mimics a game board, you are very likely going to have bugs on the edges.  When you are debugging, put a lot of attention into the 0 and array-dimension-length cases.

Comment: You might consider rethinking and refactoring.  YOU are the board creator so you already know its max and min dimensions.  With a couple of constants and a single method (that respects those constants) that allows when pointers to the board can be updated, you could prevent the indexes from ever going out of bounds.

Answer (score 0):

You keep increasing the indexes without checking the array borders. You should add this condition to your `while` loop:

```
while (x + a >= 0 &&
       x + a < boardArray.GetLength(0) &&
       y + b >= 0 &&
       y + b < boardArray.GetLength(1) &&
       boardArray[x + a, y + b] != turn)

{
    boardArray[x + a, y + b] = color;
    x += a;
    y += b;
}
```

Comment: You probably want to ditch the `=` sign in `y + b <= boardArray.GetLength(1)` and make it `y + b < boardArray.GetLength(1)`.  Ah, off-by-one errors!

Comment: When I use this code instead, it changes all squares diagonally. Even the ones that are empty

Comment: @Flydog57 yes, indeed! Thanks for noticing. Edited and fixed.

Comment: @help: That's your logic.  The crash (which was what your question was about) is fixed, right?

Comment: @Flydog57 yes, indeed the crash is fixed!